# Linked table manager with a new IP

Tags: ms-access

In my Access database, I have more than 100 tables linked to SQL Server 2012. Unfortunately, the IP of server was changed, what is the best way to link them to the new one.
I am using Access 2010, I tried through the table linked manager after selecting all tables but I am being prompted for each table.

Comment: Follow the instructions on the prompt.  There might be a lot of tables but you should only have to do this once.

Comment: You could also write some VBA code to loop through the `TableDefs` collection and update the `.Connect` property of each `TableDef` object that points to a linked table (the ones that start with "ODBC;").